# Node.js cannot find package.json and project itself

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, package.json

What do I do supposing my project cannot be found on Node.js and npm install seems not to detect my project as seen in this error:
Error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\BLOCKCHAIN EXPERIMENTAL LAB\newflowstationV2/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\BLOCKCHAIN EXPERIMEN
TAL LAB\newflowstationV2\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\peema\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-16T19_13_19_97
4Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

1. npm init
2. Make sure the package.json file and all relevant project files are found in the System Environment Variable if on  Windows
3. Include your project package.json path in the list of variables (system and user) if you have permission
   E.g. System Variable & User Variable, include :
   Path: D:\BLOCKCHAIN EXPERIMENTAL LAB\newflowstationV2\package.json
4. Include other necessary project configuration file path
5. Check within the log file:  C:\Users\peema\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-16T19_13_19_97 4Z-debug-0.log to find out more about the problem
6. You can then npm install